# How to pass data for datetime type in google visulization api server side data population

Tags: data-visualization, google-visualization

I have used Visualization table with server side polulated Data. So table data fully constructed in PHP and return as Json. In this Php,for adding a column with Time data, i try use 'datetime' type. But how to pass data to this type of column.

My column:

```
array("id"=>"ent","label"=>"Entry_time","pattern"=>"","type"=>"datetime")
```

My data:

```
array("v"=>$entry_time[$i]) //Here $entry_time[$i] is 01:00:00 pm
```

is it correct way? because of this issue AM, PM time not sorting properly in Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `array("v"=>$entry_time[$i])` to `array("v"=>Date(0,0,0,'$t[0]','$t[1]','$t[2]'))` Works fine. Here $t[0]=hours,$t[1]=minutes,$t[2]=seconds